# Handling javascript aggregation in production vs development environment

Tags: javascript, maven, yui-compressor

I use yuicompressor-maven-plugin to compress and aggregate all java scripts / css in our project. I refer the final java script/ css in all the required JSPs. This works fine in production. However, this creates a problem in development because everytime I make change to individual js / css, I am forced to rebuild for the changes to reflect. Whats the best way to organize this so that in development I will be able to make changes to individual files and see them reflecting immediately, while in production I can take advantage of the aggregation ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably depends on your setup. We use Jawr for compression and can enable/disable it for any given environment.  Enabled on prod, the pages link to one huge JS and one huge CSS file, compressed.  Disabled on local and dev, the pages return links to each of the individual JS and CSS files, uncompressed.